# how to access parent variable from child class

Tags: php, oop, class

i have two classes one parent and the other extends  ,  I need to use main vars in extended class.
for example

```
class parentClass
{
    $this->value = null
    function __construct()
    {
        echo "im parent" ;
    }

}
class childClass extends parentClass
{

    function sayIt()
    {
        var_dump($this->value);
    }
}

$p = new parentClass ; 
$p->value = 500 ; 

$c = new childClass ; 
$c->sayIt(); // this output null ! i want it to output 500 , how i can do that
```

thanks

Comment: When you create your objects they doesnt share any variables, what you actually do is copy your code that what inheritance do in oop languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Bad Bad Bad The code is strictly for educational purpose i would advice you to get a book on basic Principles of Object Oriented programming***

Making your variable static would make it accessible via the child class

```
class parentClass {
    public static $value = null;

    function __construct() {
        echo "patent called";
    }
}
class childClass extends parentClass {

    function sayIt() {
        var_dump(self::$value);
    }
}

$p = new parentClass();
parentClass::$value = 500;

$c = new childClass();
$c->sayIt();
```

Comment: Is it reasonable to use this code to share a mysql connection among child objects. So then we would have several objects that can have a same db connection. I think that would be useful when we want do some actions in several object in one transaction. if insert in object b fails insert in object a will rolls back.

Comment: @Baba care explaining why this is so bad?

Answer (score 2):

that's not the way [inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) works.  The `childClass` is not automatically connected to the parent class, it just inherits from the `parentClass` it just inherits all public and protected variables/methods from teh parent.  It is not connected to the parent's instances.

if you wnat it to output 500 you have to assign it to the child class instance somehow:

```
$c = new childClass ; 
$c->value = 500;
$c->sayIt()
```

If you need a variable shared between all classes and instances you can use a [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) variable.

Comment: so there is no any way that make me able to set data to parent using it's instance , and i could use that inside child class ? ,

Comment: If you create a child class, ahmad, it is unaware of any changes to the parent after it is created.

Answer (score 0):

you are confusing with class constructs and references.

`$p` is an instance of the parentclass.

`$c` is an instance of the childclass.

they don't share their data.