# Inheriting variables from the main class to the extended class PHP

Tags: php, class, variables, object, inheritance

I'm attempting to make a child class (feeds) inherit a variable from the main class (controller).

I have 3 files. They look as follows.

CORE FILE:

```
/*  ----------------------------- *
 *  LOAD THE CONTROLLER CLASS NOW *
 *  ----------------------------- */
 require(CORE_PATH . 'controller.php');

 require(CORE_PATH . 'load_controller.php');
```

CONTROLLER CLASS:

```
<?php

class Controller {

    var $sessions, $a;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->sessions = new Sessions();
        $this->a = 'yo';
    }
}
```

FEEDS CLASS:

```
class Feeds extends Controller {
    public function feeds() {
        /* We can load other resources here */

    }

    function index($val) {
        echo $this->a;
    }
}
```

The Fix:

```
<?php require(PROTECT);

class Controller {

    protected $variable = "Setting the variable right here works.";

    public function __construct() {
        $this->variable = "Setting it right here will only work for the current object. It's as if variable isn't being set at all when it comes to other classes.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just because the classes are related doesn't mean **separate object instances** will share the **same data**. That's not how it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access parent variable from child class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14178329/how-to-access-parent-variable-from-child-class)

Comment: @deceze - That's not what I'm trying to do. The instances are insignificant in this case. I'm simply trying to inherit $a and $sessions from the Controller class, to Feeds class, which extends controller.

When I try to access the $a variable using the $this keyword, it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, changing the variable scope from "var" to "Public" or "public static" or "static" didn't work.

Comment: That is *exactly* what you're trying to do. You're trying to instantiate one class, set values on it, than access those values from a completely different object instance. Again, that's not how it works!

Comment: @deceze, if you look carefully, you will notice that the feeds class isn't trying to get anything from the object. The objects aren't even being used for anything here. It's the classes themselves that I'm focusing on.

See how the Controller class is instantiated before the Feeds class. I need to be able to set variables to Controller, then access those variables from all extended classes, whether or not I create an object from them.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @deceze - Actually, now that I look at it again, you're right! I was relying on the constructor method to set the value of a variable, when I was supposed to set it BEFORE the constructor method. Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be having a misunderstanding about what is **instance data** and what are class properties with default values. Yes, anything set in methods of the class is specific to that one class instance. Property default values are the same for all instances of the class, but they can only be static values (i.e. `new Sessions` doesn't work as default value).

Answer (score 0):

unless your using PHP4, you should really avoid declaring class members using `var`. use `public, private, protected`

in your case since you have used `var` your member variable `$a` should be accessible from child class.

Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I am getting errors.

I've tried var, public, private, protected, and combinations of them all. Still not working. Thank you though.

I'm unable to see error logs right now, so stackoverflow is my only option. lol.